# Replace inline data with json service for angular/ionic app

Tags: json, angularjs

Can you please help to replace the below  service with json service. Right now all datas are hardcoded inside the service. the controller which binds is also below.

> services.js

angular.module('directory.services', [])

```
.factory('EmployeeService', function($q) {

    var employees = [
        {"id": 1, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "King", "managerId": 0, "managerName": "", "reports": 4, "title": "President and CEO", "department": "Corporate", "cellPhone": "617-000-0001", "officePhone": "781-000-0001", "email": "jking@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "James_King.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejking", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 2, "firstName": "Julie", "lastName": "Taylor", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 2, "title": "VP of Marketing", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0002", "officePhone": "781-000-0002", "email": "jtaylor@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Julie_Taylor.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejtaylor", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 3, "firstName": "Eugene", "lastName": "Lee", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 0, "title": "CFO", "department": "Accounting", "cellPhone": "617-000-0003", "officePhone": "781-000-0003", "email": "elee@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Eugene_Lee.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeelee", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 4, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Williams", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 3, "title": "VP of Engineering", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0004", "officePhone": "781-000-0004", "email": "jwilliams@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "John_Williams.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejwilliams", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 5, "firstName": "Ray", "lastName": "Moore", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 2, "title": "VP of Sales", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0005", "officePhone": "781-000-0005", "email": "rmoore@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Ray_Moore.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakermoore", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 6, "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "Jones", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "QA Manager", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0006", "officePhone": "781-000-0006", "email": "pjones@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Paul_Jones.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakepjones", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 7, "firstName": "Paula", "lastName": "Gates", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "Software Architect", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0007", "officePhone": "781-000-0007", "email": "pgates@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Paula_Gates.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakepgates", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 8, "firstName": "Lisa", "lastName": "Wong", "managerId": 2, "managerName": "Julie Taylor", "reports": 0, "title": "Marketing Manager", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0008", "officePhone": "781-000-0008", "email": "lwong@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Lisa_Wong.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakelwong", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 9, "firstName": "Gary", "lastName": "Donovan", "managerId": 2, "managerName": "Julie Taylor", "reports": 0, "title": "Marketing Manager", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0009", "officePhone": "781-000-0009", "email": "gdonovan@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Gary_Donovan.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakegdonovan", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 10, "firstName": "Kathleen", "lastName": "Byrne", "managerId": 5, "managerName": "Ray Moore", "reports": 0, "title": "Sales Representative", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0010", "officePhone": "781-000-0010", "email": "kbyrne@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Kathleen_Byrne.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakekbyrne", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 11, "firstName": "Amy", "lastName": "Jones", "managerId": 5, "managerName": "Ray Moore", "reports": 0, "title": "Sales Representative", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0011", "officePhone": "781-000-0011", "email": "ajones@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Amy_Jones.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeajones", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 12, "firstName": "Steven", "lastName": "Wells", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "Software Architect", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0012", "officePhone": "781-000-0012", "email": "swells@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "Steven_Wells.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeswells", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"}
    ];

    // We use promises to make this api asynchronous. This is clearly not necessary when using in-memory data
    // but it makes this service more flexible and plug-and-play. For example, you can now easily replace this
    // service with a JSON service that gets its data from a remote server without having to changes anything
    // in the modules invoking the data service since the api is already async.

    return {
        findAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(employees);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findById: function(employeeId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var employee = employees[employeeId - 1];
            deferred.resolve(employee);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findByName: function(searchKey) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var results = employees.filter(function(element) {
                var fullName = element.firstName + " " + element.lastName;
                return fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findByManager: function (managerId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                results = employees.filter(function (element) {
                    return parseInt(managerId) === element.managerId;
                });
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }

});
```

> controller.js

angular.module('directory.controllers', [])

```
.controller('EmployeeIndexCtrl', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {

    $scope.searchKey = "";

    $scope.clearSearch = function () {
        $scope.searchKey = "";
        findAllEmployees();
    }

    $scope.search = function () {
        EmployeeService.findByName($scope.searchKey).then(function (employees) {
            $scope.employees = employees;
        });
    }

    var findAllEmployees = function() {
        EmployeeService.findAll().then(function (employees) {
            $scope.employees = employees;
        });
    }

    findAllEmployees();

})

.controller('EmployeeDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, EmployeeService) {
    EmployeeService.findById($stateParams.employeeId).then(function(employee) {
        $scope.employee = employee;
    });
})

.controller('EmployeeReportsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, EmployeeService) {
    EmployeeService.findByManager($stateParams.employeeId).then(function(employees) {
        $scope.employees = employees;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to make integrate some API calls in these deferred promises, right?

Well, instead of doing this:

```
    return {
        findAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(employees);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findById: function(employeeId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var employee = employees[employeeId - 1];
            deferred.resolve(employee);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
     }
```

Just make your call inside the `findSomething` method

```
    return {
        findAll: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // simple get to an hypothetical url 
            $http.get('http://your.api.server.com/all')
                .then(function(data) {
                     deferred.resolve(data)
                 })

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        findById: function(employeeId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // this is a simple post that have to be customized, of course
            $http.post('http://your.api.server.com/byId', {id:employeeId})
                .then(function(data) {
                     deferred.resolve(data)
                 })

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit:**
if you want instead simply get your data from a JSON file, just use

```
    $http.get('employee.json').
        then(function(data) {
            // this 'data' will contain your employees
            deferred.resolve(data)
        })
```

Comment: in the service you can find var employees = [....];. I have removed that array and  put into a json file and saved separately. I just want to get data from that json file. i am not able to make the changes in factory and controllers correctly.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to get a JSON, which is no different from any other promise, actually.

Comment: the code still breaks. i have updated the question. can you look at it once more

Comment: You are not supposed to copy paste the code and hope it works...
Provide me a Plunker that exactly displays the error so I could help you. Remember that Stack Overflow provides help, not work for free.